# cmake detect flags during build using another tool

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I'm faced a problem how to add 3rd-party dependency library to link command using cmake. 
Currently, my cmake build does the following :

- gets 3rd-party library from git and builds it (ExternalProject_Add)
- after building of 3rd-party libarry, it provides custom binary file
  (named 'config++') that allows to invoke it with the following
  arguments :

  - 'config++ --cppflags' - to get CPPFLAGS being used to
    compile with the library
  - 'config++ --ldflags' - to get library path
    where libraries are placed during bulding
  - 'config++ --libs' - to get
    list of libraries (inluding static and shared dependent libaries) to
    be used when linking with the libary.

(Yes, config++ it is very similar to pkg-config.)

As 3rd-party libary build is done during project build and I don't have config++ ready before, is there any way to detect dynamically CXXFLAGS/LDFLAGS (by invoking 'config++') to be passed to compile/linkage command when performing 'cmake build'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CMake command [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) to run the external program and then collect its output in a variable that you can then append to your build flags.

Comment: Generally, you are right. But the use-case is like this : 
$ ./GraphicsMagick++-config --libs
-lGraphicsMagick++ -lGraphicsMagick -ljbig -llcms2 -ltiff -lfreetype -ljasper -ljpeg -lpng12 -lwmflite -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -llzma -lbz2 -lxml2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread
There are 3 problems:
1. newline at the end of output
2. I need to replace -lGraphicsMagick++ -lGraphicsMagick with static libraries
3. I need too convert command output '-lGraphicsMagick++...' to a list and pass it to link_libraries()